# Servlet mapping url mapping issue with spring and BIRT

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, birt

In my application I'm using spring MVC(3.0.5) architecture along with BIRT reporting framework.

I'm trying to serve all requests including the static resources like `css`, `js`, `html` and image files using the spring `DispatcherServlet`.

For this purpose I added the following entries to my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

...............
...............

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This will direct all request to the `DispatcherServlet` and in my context file I added

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/docs/**" location="/docs/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/themes/**" location="/themes/" />
```

so that these resources will be loaded from the file system.

These configurations are working fine. But I'm facing issues with my BIRT reporting engine now.

The BIRT reporting engine uses some jsp files located in a folder called webcontent which is located at the root of the application. Since we are directing all request to `DispatcherServlet` even the request for these jsp pages are going to the spring servlet. As I understand from some posts the jsp files are normally handled by `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` which is registered in the Apache Tomcat's `web.xml` file and it has a servlet mapping as follows

```
<!-- The mapping for the JSP servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What are the changes that I should make in my servlet mapping to work in this environment? I need the jsp files to be handled by the default jsp servlet not by the spring servlet. How can I achieve this?

For [this post](http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/) I understood that the second priority in servlet matching is for the url prefix, so my url pattern `/` for spring servelt is overriding the default jsp servlet mapping, Is this assumption correct? If it is correct then how to overcome this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The typical mapping of `DispatcherServlet` is `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`. In this case it still handles all requests except for requests handled by other servlets (in particular, requests to `*.jsp`), so that it should solve the problem.